# How to set XACT_ABORT within ADO.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, transactions

How can I set XACT_ABORT to ON (or OFF) from within ADO.NET ?

Comment: How can you accept answers to your questions?  Good question!  Click the green checkmark on the best answer ;)

Answer (score 9):

Execute `SET XACT_ABORT ON` or `SET XACT_ABORT OFF`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no client setting: in SQL As Remus said.

SET XACT_ABORT is not a property of the connection, command or transaction and can be set/unset at any time in SQL Code. There is no ado.net options for SET NOCOUNT ON etc.