# SqlTransaction multiple commands: Order of Execution?

Tags: sql, ado.net, transactions

I'm using `SqlTransaction` to make a series of changes to multiple tables with FK relationships.  It begins with the deletions of the records via an ID then moves on to foreach loops for the inserts.  If the deletions do "not" occur then it will, of course, fail.  I've stepped into it multiple times and I still get this error.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK__xxxx_P_*Reque*_3C69FB99". The conflict occurred in database
>   "xxxxx", table "dbo.xxxxx", column 'Request_ID'.

Unless I'm missing something, this is occurring because the inserts are being attempted before the deletions.  Is there and order of execution that I am not aware of?

Comment: I had a similar problem to this once.  Are you using a Stored Procedure to execute the deletions? If so, have a look at XACT_ABORT (this is an SQL command).

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  This is ADO only, some jquery $.ajax stuff. It was decided and SP would be more trouble that is was worth.

Comment: Does this help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277254/how-to-set-xact-abort-within-ado-net.  I had a problem once where I would loop through some records for deletion and after each deletion set a flag to indicate it was successful.  Sometimes the flag would set before the deletion took place (even if the deletion subsuequently failed).  Hence I was left with 1000+ flags indicating successful deletions even though only 99% were deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key conflict indicates that you are inserting a row into a child table where the corresponding row in the parent table is missing. That is, you need to insert a row into the parent first.

It has nothing to do with deletions failing.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Let this stand as an example of how the simplest things can be right in front of you.  I used the same order for insertion that I used for deletion and forgot to reverse the insert order, duh.  Thanks Ben.